# Iterate Struct (map key) value in golang

Tags: go

I've looked up [Structs as keys in Golang maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064244/structs-as-keys-in-golang-maps)

I understand iteration over the maps in golang has no guaranteed order. I've followed the [example in golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.), and tried using a `struct` as a map key.

Here's my code

```
package main

func main() {
    req := make(map[mapKey]string)

    req[mapKey{1, "r"}] = "robpike"
    req[mapKey{2, "gri"}] = "robert griesemer"
    req[mapKey{3, "adg"}] = "andrew gerrand"
    req[mapKey{4, "rsc"}] = "russ cox"

    var keys []int
    for k := range req {
        keys = append(keys, k.Key)
    }

    for _, k := range keys {
        fmt.Printf("short name : %s , long name : %s\n",req[k], req[k]) // How do I iterate here
    }

    sort.Ints(keys)
}

type mapKey struct {
    Key    int
    Option string
}
```

What I want the results to be is

```
short name : r , long name : rob pike
short name : gri , long name : robert griesemer
short name : adg , long name : andrew gerrand
short name : rsc , long name : russ cox
```

And I don't know how I can get the struct value and key iterated by separated data structure.

Comment: Oh I think I have found something similar [golang map prints out of order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108215/golang-map-prints-out-of-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version? You can't do it that way.

Long version you, you can use a custom sorter:

```
func main() {
    req := make(map[mapKey]string)

    req[mapKey{1, "r"}] = "robpike"
    req[mapKey{2, "gri"}] = "robert griesemer"
    req[mapKey{3, "adg"}] = "andrew gerrand"
    req[mapKey{4, "rsc"}] = "russ cox"

    var keys mapKeys
    for k := range req {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Sort(keys)
    for _, k := range keys {
        fmt.Printf("short name : %s , long name : %s\n", k.Option, req[k])
    }
}

type mapKey struct {
    Key    int
    Option string
}

type mapKeys []mapKey

func (mk mapKeys) Len() int           { return len(mk) }
func (mk mapKeys) Swap(i, j int)      { mk[i], mk[j] = mk[j], mk[i] }
func (mk mapKeys) Less(i, j int) bool { return mk[i].Key < mk[j].Key }
```

<kbd>[play](http://play.golang.org/p/fygmN7hg-4)</kbd>

Keep in mind that if your `mapKey` struct have a field that doesn't support equality (aka a struct or a slice) using `req[k]` won't work.

In that case you can switch to `type mapKeys []*mapKey` and `map[*mapKey]string`.